# Symlinks and their paths are confusing - how can they be used effectively?

Tags: filesystem, shortcuts

When exploring directories from a symlink (symbolic link) using Nautilus or Gnome Commander, the directory structure is displayed as if the symlink were a regular directory.  When I open a document, apps differ in how they treat the path.  For an .html document:

- opened w/ Firefox: Shows the real
  path as the address
- opened w/ NetBeans:   ditto
- opened w/ Gedit: Shows the **symlink**
  path as the address

---

1. Do I need to pay attention to these
   varying behaviors?
2. I feel insecure when the symlink
   path is offered (because of my
   Windows background) -- can I ignore
   that?  Can I proceed with
   confidence, and if so, does that
   cover all cases?
3. An app will occasionally ask me if I
   want to preserve symlinks, treat
   symlinks as actual links, and so on.
   (ex., copying in Gnome Commander presents 
   an option called "follow links" ... which
   I *assume* means symlinks).
   Your guidelines for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not really, because either way you are still viewing/editing the files that the symlink is pointing to
2. When the symlink path is given, I think it means that the application *thinks* that the file is at that path; however, the data is still being read from/written to the same place in the file system (the original file). So yes, you can ignore it.
3. 'Preserving symlinks', in my understanding, means that when you move a symlink file and it points to a relative path, the relative path will be adjusted so that it still points to the same file. It is probably a good idea to preserve symlinks. 'follow links' means that the action you are doing (such as copy) is done to the linked to files and all the files within the linked to directories. I think that if you follow links when copying, the actual files/folders will be copied to the new location. If you don't follow links, only the link is copied to the new address.

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) has a detailed explanation of symlinks

Comment: +1. You should quote each question before you answer it - will be more readable.

Comment: I thought the use of question numbers was adequate, myself.

Comment: Thanks, helpful answer.  I have looked at the wikipedia article before, but I think it seemed too techie (as well as others I found) -- today it seemed to get more clear as I pressed on.

Answer (score 1):

1. This might be a two-sided sword. In some way, for a casual user, the indication of a symlink might be confusing, while for an advanced user might be important. Maybe it would be good if those file browsers would have a configuration option that could make them give the functionality that is needed.
2. Not sure what you are insecure about. If you follow a symlink, it is not different as if it would be a normal path. It gives you additional flexibility in that you can change directories or files that are used. It is like an alias. Several names for the same thing.
3. When you copy a tree of directories, it makes a difference. You can either ignore all symlinks, and only copy all "real" directories or files, or copy the symlinks as symlinks, i.e. copy exactly the same, or duplicate the trees (or files) that are behind symlinks to distinct copies.

Comment: "...it makes a different."  Typo?  "makes a difference" or "makes a different *something*"?

Comment: When changing a file, knowing about symbolic links is important! Suppose I have `./file -> /etc/hosts`. If I edit `./file`, I'll see the contents of `/etc/hosts`, but when I save, the symbolic link will be broken (I don't have write access to `/etc/hosts`), and I'll end up with my own copy of `./file`, which will no longer track changes to `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Also the commmand [readlink](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_readlink.htm) might also come in handy from the terminal if your ever unsure about were a particular symlink is directed to.

Useage:

```
readlink [symlink]
```

Comment: You can also see this with ls.